# Caching of QML files

Tags: qt, qml

I use a common common.qrc module (with QML components and javascript code) that is linked against different plugins at **different build times**.

I must make sure that every plugin uses the version of the component it was designed with (at build time that is chosen).

In common.qrc I have

```
<qresource prefix="/Comp1Common">
    <file alias="NotificationDrawer.qml">NotificationDrawer.qml</file>
    <file alias="Drawer.qml">Drawer.qml</file>
</qresource
<qresource prefix="/Comp2Common">
    <file alias="NotificationDrawer.qml">NotificationDrawer.qml</file>
    <file alias="Drawer.qml">Drawer.qml</file>
</qresource
```

This way I can import in Comp1 the corresponding Common version (and that will not clash with the same common version of a component built at another time) by using

```
import Comp1Common
```

This is all good. But If I want to use singletons (still defined in common.qrc) defined as follows (in corresponding qmldir in common.qrc)

```
singleton Comp Comp.qml
```

Every time I would use Comp that is a singleton it would pick the first loaded version (for first loaded plugin) of that and not choose what is linked at build time in current plugin.

The described versioning works for non sigleton instances only.
LE: Further tests showed that normal instantiation (e.g Drawer.qml) is affected by cache also. The first component loaded by first plugin is used by second one.

Comment: Is it necessary the Comp be a singleton? As far as I know singleton is essentially static, it would be non-trivial to reload it or re-evaluate the reference to Comp during runtime.

Comment: @dabbler I updated my findings. It fails also for non singletons also. Cannot make it so that caching does not affect proper loading of Drawer for example.

Comment: Possibly you can call [QQmlEngine::trimComponentCache](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#trimComponentCache) to unload the non singleton stuff, not sure about the singleton cache, but worth a shot

Comment: That's unfortunate, though not surprising. It seems you may need to rearchitect your "plugin" setup a bit. Perhaps you could do something like move the component registration out to C++, expose a versioned instance of the plugin interface via [qmlRegisterType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType-2), and then have the plugin QML import the expected versioned type (which gives access to the correct versions of the components). Should be doable since you highlight this is done at build time.

Comment: Turns out I used aliases/prefix in a dumb way. The problem is that I needed the use a different prefix every time I updated my common.qrc. that way every plugin uses the local resources if import statement says it needs to use a specific version. Something like import CompCommonVx.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I used aliases/prefix in a dumb way. The problem is that I needed the use a different prefix every time I updated my common.qrc. that way every plugin uses the local resources if import statement says it needs to use a specific version. Something like import CompCommonVx.